# An empty Angular2 app has 911k vendor.js after uglify. How to make Angular2 web app smaller?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am 100% following the [official guide here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) to build an starter Angular2 and webpack project.

After production build success, I found out the

- app.js is 2k,
- polyfill.js is 98k
- vendor.js is 911k

Those sizes are after uglify and minify.

- What else do I need to do to make angular2 app smaller (especially vendor.js)?
- I heared about "tree shaking", can you share some samples on how to do it?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this an Angular CLI app, add AoT to the build:

ng build --prod --aot

1. You'll get potentially smaller sizes of the files even though at this point AoT seems to be making good impact on smaller apps (your case) and not on the large ones.
2. As @EternalLight mentioned, use the Web server that can serve
   pre-created gziped files, e.g. Node Static
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static. Take a look at the sample
   package.json here: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter10/angular2-webpack-starter/package.json

Answer (score 1):

Surely, Angular 2 is famous for its size. I suggest:

1. Set up your web server to serve gzipped JS-files. My Angular 2 application's main JS file (with a bunch of third-party ng2 modules) is about 1.6 Mb. But it seems to be only 337 Kb after gzipping.
2. Cache your main JavaScript file (and other static assets) with a service worker, so that you users have to download it fully only for the first time.